# Spectral Clustering perform bad, while perform Kmeans directly on the data seems well, Why?

Tags: clustering

I use `sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering` for clustering(I used the default set for `SpectralClustering`, I paste the log below) the data set $X$. What I want is separate them into 10 groups. But the clustering algorithm, classified almost all of them into one group. Only a few of single points have been separated into other groups. If I perform $Kmeans$ directly on the data $X$(normalized), it well separated into 10 groups. Why? I thought that $spectral clustering$ should perform well too. Because Its obvious that there are 10 groups (I use the $PCA$ to visualize the data).

log info:

`spectral = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=10)
spectral
SpectralClustering(affinity='rbf', assign_labels='kmeans', coef0=1, degree=3,
          eigen_solver=None, eigen_tol=0.0, gamma=1.0, kernel_params=None,
          n_clusters=10, n_init=10, n_neighbors=10, random_state=None)`

Answer (score 1):

Why did you choose the parameters this way?

For example, the `rbf` kernel *requires* you to tune the kernel bandwidth $\sigma$ carefully, which won't be feasible in unsupervised clustering.

Simply by setting this parameter too small or too large, you can ruin spectral clustering results.

Comment: I don't know how to choose it, so I left it as default. Is there any materials for parameters? I just started, don't know much about the logic behind parameters. Could you please give me some tips?

Comment: I rarely ever use spectral clustering, because of this and performance.